# not returning the whole pattern in regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I have the following code:

```
haystack = "aaa months(3) bbb"
needle = re.compile(r'(months|days)\([\d]*\)')
instances = list(set(needle.findall(haystack)))
print str(instances)
```

I'd expect it to print `months(3)` but instead I just get `months`. Is there any reason for this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [re.findall not returning full match?](/q/18425386/90527)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
needle = re.compile(r'((?:months|days)\([\d]*\))')
```

fixes your problem.

you were capturing only the months|days part.

in this specific situation, this regex is a bit better:

```
needle = re.compile(r'((?:months|days)\(\d+\))')
```

this way you will only get results with a number, previously a result like `months()` would work. if you want to ignore case for options like Months or Days, then also add the `re.IGNORECASE` flag. like this:

```
re.compile(r'((?:months|days)\(\d+\))', re.IGNORECASE)
```

**some explanation for the OP:**

a regular expression is comprised of many elements, the chief among them is the capturing group. "`()`" but sometimes we want to make groups without capturing, so we use "`(?:)`" there are many other forms of groups, but these are the most common.

in this case, we surround the entire regular expression in a capturing group, because you are trying to capture everything, normally - any regular expression is automatically surrounded by a capturing group, but in this case, you specified one explicitly, so it did not surround your regular expression with an automatic capture group.

now that we have surrounded the entire regular expression with a capturing group, we turn the group we have into a non-capturing group by adding `?:` to the beginning, as shown above. we could also not have surrounded the entire regular expression and only turned the group into a non-capturing group, since as you saw, it will automatically turn the whole regular expression into a capturing group where non is present. i personally prefer explicit coding.

further information about regular expressions can be found here: http://docs.python.org/library/re.html

Comment: Could you break that up for us? What does `?:` mean, and why does the whole thing need to be encapsulated in `(...)`

Comment: i will refer you to this: http://docs.python.org/library/re.html but i will also explain a little bit in my answer

Comment: The all-enclosing parens are superfluous when using `findall`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Regular expression is quite a complex subject and I have a feel I have a lot more to learn

Answer (score 1):

Parens are not just for grouping, but also for forming capture groups.  What you want is `re.compile(r'(?:months|days)\(\d+\)')`.  That uses a non-capturing group for the or condition, and will not get you a bunch of subgroup matches you don't appear to want when using findall.